# Tomcat 8.5.39 error "the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists"

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

This may be kind of a broad question and I don't have a lot of details.  But here it is.

I am trying to access an application on a new laptop that our company cursed us with.  I am running Tomcat 8.5.39 on a Mac laptop. I go to http://localhost:8080 and this then forwards to http://localhost:8080/mygroup/module/app/index.html#/login

I get a 404 error and the message "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists".

Where is it looking for the index.html file?  Tomcat is installed at /home/mstabosz/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.39 and index.html is at /home/mstabosz/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.39/webapps/mygroup/module/app/index.html

Normally I would think that this is a problem in web.xml or server.xml or some configuration file and I would include some of those files.  But it is running code pulled from Git that works perfectly fine on my old laptop, which is also a Mac.

Tried the following:

- Navigate to JSP files in other subdirectories of the "app" directory.
- Navigate to other HTML files in the "app" directory.
- Try a different version of Tomcat.